# QGIS 2.14 Debian Sid - Couldn't load plugin 'processing'

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

The processing plugin can't load because python import error for QtWebKit.QWebView.

QGIS is installed from Debian official repositories. The plugin worked fine until 2.14.1.

The error message at startup :

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

ImportError: No module named QtWebKit.QWebView 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 281, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 28, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 44, in 
    from processing.gui.Postprocessing import handleAlgorithmResults
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/Postprocessing.py", line 39, in 
    from processing.gui.ResultsDialog import ResultsDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/ResultsDialog.py", line 38, in 
    os.path.join(pluginPath, 'ui', 'DlgResults.ui'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/__init__.py", line 211, in loadUiType
    exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)
  File "", line 52, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named QtWebKit.QWebView


Python version: 2.7.12rc1 (default, Jun 13 2016, 09:20:59) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] 
QGIS version: 2.14.3-Essen Essen, exported 

Python Path:
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/pierma/.qgis2/python
/home/pierma/.qgis2/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/home/pierma/.qgis2//python
```

Not sure if the issue comes from QGIS 2.14.2 update or from Qt/pyqt update. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: This is happening to me on a Debian Stretch system, but only since QGIS 2.14.3. I am unable to test @Matte's suggestion becasue of broken dependencies with the official Debian QGIS repository.

Comment: Just bumping this. Official debian repo still broken, unable to update or test @Matte 's suggestion.

Comment: Everything works for me since 2.14.4 update with debian Sid official repo.

Comment: There must be something wrong with my system. 2.14.4 has hit Stretch but I can't upgrade. Thanks for the heads up @Pierma!

Comment: The recent combination of the QGIS upgrade to 2.14.3 and installing the following packages solved the problem for me on Debian Stretch:
pyqt4-dev-tools 
pyqt5-dev
pyqt5-dev-tools
pyqt5-doc 
pyqt5-examples 
pyqt5.qsci-dev
python-dev
python-pyqt5.qtsvg 
python-qt4-dev 
python-qtawesome 
python-qtawesome-common 
python-qtpy 
python-sip-dev 
python2.7-dev 
python3-dev 
python3-sip-dev 
python3.5-dev 
qt4-default 
qt4-dev-tools 
qt4-doc 
qt4-qmlviewer 
qt4-qtconfig

Answer (score 2):

Could be a problem of the development branch of debian. Its meant for developers that will test and search for possible bugs like that one might be. You could install Qgis from the offical Qgis repository and see if it delivers the correct modules and works. In general i would stay with the stable or at least testing release if i don´t want to fix those problems.